# Provider is used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, provider

i have a flutter provider that that is in charge of app settings like this,

```
class AppProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

dynamic _appSettinngs;

AppProvider() {

_loadAppSettings();
}

  void _loadAppSettings() {
dynamic tempSttings = {"biometrics": false, "showBalance": false};
_localStorage.getAll('security').then((value) {
  if (value == null) {
    _appSettinngs = tempSttings;
    notifyListeners();
    _localStorage.save("security", tempSttings);
  } else {
    _appSettinngs = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
});
```

}

```
void updateOptions(String option, bool value) {
_appSettinngs[option] = value;
_localStorage.save("security", _appSettinngs);
_loadAppSettings();
```

}

```
}
```

so basically i'm trying to update the app settings using a switcher widget like this

```
Switch(
  value: Provider.of<AppProvider>(context)
              .appOptions['showBalance'],
    onChanged: (value) =>
        Provider.of<AppProvider>(context, listen: false)
              .updateOptions("showBalance", value),
          ),
```

but when i try to toggle the setting, i get this error

```
Unhandled Exception: A AppProvider was used after being disposed.
```

what am i getting wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem was that i used a singleton instance while creating my provider so all i had to do was not use a singleton and it took care of the error